# Jquery input value optional after -dash

Tags: jquery

I have an input phone number field filed where I am using `$('#pocContactInput').mask('09999999999-99999999999')`. the issue is that after dash - thevalue can be optional. but it demands every value should be there with formate please help I am begginer

```js
$('#ContactInput').mask('09999999999-99999999999')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<label class="control-label" for="ContactInput">
  <strong>POC Contact: (without dash)</strong>
</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="23" placeholder="e.g 03xxxxxxxxx-03xxxxxxxxx" id="ContactInput" oninput="update()">
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html) (Translation > Optional digits), you could try :

```js
$('#ContactInput').mask('09999999999-ZZZZZZZZZZZ', 
  {translation:  
    {
      'Z': {pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<label for="ContactInput">POC Contact: (without dash)</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g 03xxxxxxxxx-03xxxxxxxxx" id="ContactInput" />
```